# Updating one column on 2 million rows based off of arithmetic to another column

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

I am trying to update one column of null values on about 2 million rows after performing some math on a different column in the same table. Basically, I am converting minutes from one column to seconds, and updating the null column with the seconds based on some criteria. I have tried this without a cursor but it takes incredibly too long and does not complete. The script below also seems to never complete. This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE
CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT /*+ ORDERED USE_NL(g,e) */
        e.event_code, e.time, e.period, e.time_elapsed, e.rowid
    FROM table1.schedule s, table2.event e
    WHERE e.event_code = s.event_code                
    AND s.schedule_id in (22,39,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63,65,66,
    68,69,71,72,75,77,78,80,82,84,86,87,89,92,93,95,97,98,
    101,103,105,107,109,111,114,116,118,120,122,125,128,130,
    133,135,137,140,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,67,70,73,74,76,79,
    81,83,85,88,90,91,94,96,99,100,102,104,106,108,110,112,113,
    115,117,119,121,123,124,126,127,129,131,132,134,136,138,141)
    AND e.time_elapsed IS NULL
    AND e.time IS NOT NULL
    AND (e.period > 0 OR e.period < 0);


TYPE EventRecType IS RECORD (
    Event_Code table1.schedule.event_code%type,
    evTime table2.event.time%type,
    evPeriod table2.event.period%type,
    evTimeElapsed table2.event.time_elapsed%TYPE,
    evRowId ROWID);

TYPE EventRecTab IS TABLE OF EventRecType INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

EventRec EventRecTab;

TYPE typ_evRecord IS RECORD (
  eRowId ROWID,
  TimeElapsed table2.event.time_elapsed%TYPE);

TYPE tab_evTable IS TABLE OF typ_evRecord INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

arr_evRecToUpdate tab_evTable;

BEGIN
  OPEN c1;
  LOOP
  FETCH c1 BULK COLLECT INTO EventRec LIMIT 50000; 

  FOR k in 1..EventRec.count LOOP
     if  EventRec(k).evPeriod = 1 AND EventRec(k).evTime < 150 then
       arr_evRecToUpdate(k).TimeElapsed := EventRec(k).evTime*60;
       arr_evRecToUpdate(k).eRowId := EventRec(k).evRowId;  
     elsif EventRec(k).evPeriod = 2 AND EventRec(k).evTime < 150 then          
       arr_evRecToUpdate(k).TimeElapsed := (EventRec(k).evTime-45)*60;
       arr_evRecToUpdate(k).eRowId := EventRec(k).evRowId;   
     elsif EventRec(k).evPeriod = 3 AND EventRec(k).evTime < 150 then    
       arr_evRecToUpdate(k).TimeElapsed := (EventRec(k).evTime-90)*60;
       arr_evRecToUpdate(k).eRowId := EventRec(k).evRowId;      
     elsif EventRec(k).evPeriod = 4 AND EventRec(k).evTime < 150 then      
       arr_evRecToUpdate(k).TimeElapsed := (EventRec(k).evTime-105)*60;
       arr_evRecToUpdate(k).eRowId := EventRec(k).evRowId; 
     elsif EventRec(k).evPeriod = 1 AND EventRec(k).evTime > 150 THEN    
       EventRec(k).evTime := ROUND(EventRec(k).evTime/60);                         
       arr_evRecToUpdate(k).TimeElapsed := EventRec(k).evTime;
       arr_evRecToUpdate(k).eRowId := EventRec(k).evRowId;  
     elsif (EventRec(k).evPeriod = 2) AND (EventRec(k).evTime > 150) THEN     
       EventRec(k).evTime := ROUND((EventRec(k).evTime/60)) + 45;              
       arr_evRecToUpdate(k).TimeElapsed := EventRec(k).evTime;
       arr_evRecToUpdate(k).eRowId := EventRec(k).evRowId;
     end if;

     EXIT WHEN EventRec.COUNT() = 0;
    END LOOP;
    FORALL i_loopIndex IN 1 .. arr_evRecToUpdate.COUNT
      UPDATE table2.event
      SET time_elapsed = arr_evRecToUpdate(i_loopIndex).TimeElapsed
      WHERE rowid = arr_evRecToUpdate(i_loopIndex).eRowid;
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;        
 CLOSE c1;
END;
```

Comment: Can you use staging table instead of cursors here? Populate staging table using insert/select and then update main table from staging table joining on keys?

Comment: The non-cursor query is probably going to be the faster solution in the end.  You should post that too so that people who wish to assist you can have more to work with.

Comment: What are TABLE1.SCHEDULE and TABLE2.EVENT? Are those tables (and thus are TABLE1 and TABLE2 schemas)? Or are SCHEDULE and EVENT object columns in TABLE1 and TABLE2?

Comment: looping is a performance killer.  why not move your conditions either to a function or CASE statement?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have no experience with using staging tables but am willing to give that a try if I can understand how to accomplish that. Less than a year experience using Oracle/SQL so please bare with me. Table1 and Table2 are schemas. I tried using case statements like in the post below but was a getting a invalid host/bind variable error.

Answer (score 1):

Is you `SELECT` Query consuming time when ran individually?
Please read my points below. It wont solve your problem, but may help you!

**Points to consider:**

1) All the Data you `BULK COLLECT` into a `PL/SQL` Collection is going to be put up in `PGA`, and it is static. If any other `PL/SQL` blocks using collection are running in background, all will be using the `PGA` and it is not shared too. It is definitely a costly operation, when the collection is huge and here you do the operation in batch of `50K` for more than `40` times. Of course you call them using (`subscript`), which is similar to querying a table using its `index`.

The `bulk bind` will consume time in `PL/SQL engine` itself, before sent to the `SQL Engine`. Your approach of using `ROWID` is great. I don't say PL/SQL collection should never be used. It depends on how busy the database is. You will be holding the 2M result set in PGA too till you CURSOR is exhausted! Better talk to DBA and have the PGA increased if possible.

My take is processing 2M rows in PGA, is not good.

2) As some one in the comments suggested, having a `staging table` is good too. I have written update operations by splitting it into multiple parallel running scripts. That could take some more coding.

3) `COMMIT` size. Your `COMMIT` size is `50K` here. Higher the commit size, more the size of `redo` / `undo` logs. Is this table replicated? These tables do have any `triggers`?

4) There are so many file processing scripts available(`perl`). Download the Query data to a file, do file processing and reload the table if possible.(This may favour , when the to-be-updated count is >=50% of total )

Comment: Hi Maheswaran. Thank you for your input. You are correct, as I believe this is being put into an infinite loop. There are triggers on this table as well that I cannot disable. I do not beleive this update is >=50% of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Updating a table is a slow process.  Your main problem here is that you have a query which you need to execute first before you can update your rows.  All the usual questions about query tuning apply here: how many rows are there in the base table?  what percentage of them will be selected (updated)?  how are they distributed across the table? what indexes do you have?  what does the execution plan look like?

So, you need to tune that query first.  If this is a one-off exercise perhaps building an index is too big an investment, but I would certainly consider building one on: `EVENTS(event_code, period, time_elapsed, time,  event_primary_key)`  otherwise.

I have become a big fan of MERGE as a way of executing updates which draw data from more than one table, given that Oracle doesn't support the ANSI 92 join syntax for anything other than SELECTs.

The following may not be quite correct but it does illustrate the general principle.

```
merge into table2.event e
    using ( SELECT e.event_code, e.time, e.period, e.time_elapsed, e.event_primary_key
             , case 
     when  e.evPeriod = 1 AND e.evTime < 150 then
       e.evTime*60;       
     when e.evPeriod = 2 AND e.evTime < 150 then          
       (e.evTime-45)*60;        
     when e.evPeriod = 3 AND e.evTime < 150 then    
       (e.evTime-90)*60;           
     when e.evPeriod = 4 AND e.evTime < 150 then      
       (e.evTime-105)*60;
     when e.evPeriod = 1 AND e.evTime > 150 THEN    
       ROUND(e.evTime/60);                         
     when (e.evPeriod = 2) AND (e.evTime > 150) THEN     
       e.evTime := ROUND((e.evTime/60)) + 45;              
 end as TimeElapsed
    FROM table1.schedule s, table2.event e
    WHERE e.event_code = s.event_code                
    AND s.schedule_id in (22,39,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63,65,66,
    68,69,71,72,75,77,78,80,82,84,86,87,89,92,93,95,97,98,
    101,103,105,107,109,111,114,116,118,120,122,125,128,130,
    133,135,137,140,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,67,70,73,74,76,79,
    81,83,85,88,90,91,94,96,99,100,102,104,106,108,110,112,113,
    115,117,119,121,123,124,126,127,129,131,132,134,136,138,141)
    AND e.time_elapsed IS NULL
    AND e.time IS NOT NULL
    AND (e.period > 0 OR e.period < 0) q
on (q.event_primary_key = e.event_primary_key)
when matched then
    update
    set e.time_elapsed = q.TimeElapsed;
```

Comment: MERGE is fine but a bit useless when you have *only* an UPDATE

Comment: @Wernfried - not sure what you mean.  MERGE works perfectly well like this, and I think it's easier to read than an UPDATE with an in-line view.  YMMV.

Comment: In my opinion it's a matter of taste which one is easier to read. MERGE works perfectly, of course. But I would not use it straight forward unless I have to do an INSERT **and** an UPDATE.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use this hint `/*+ ORDERED USE_NL(g,e) */`? Nested-Loop Joins are suitable only for small tables. Big tables are usually joined by Hash-Join.

Like the other answer, the loop slows down your operation in general. Using a single DML is in almost every case the fasted way.

Try this one, `UPDATE (SELECT ... FROM ...) SET =` looks a bit uncommon but it works fine.

```
UPDATE 
    (SELECT e.time_elapsed, e.evPeriod, e.evTime
    FROM table1.schedule s
        JOIN table2.event e ON e.event_code = s.event_code
   WHERE s.schedule_id in (22,39,49,51,53,55,57,59,61,63,65,66,68,69,71,72,75,77,78,80,82,84,86,87,89,92,93,95,97,98,101,103,105,107,109,111,114,16,118,120,122,125,128,130,133,135,137,140,50,52,54,56,58,60,62,64,67,70,73,74,76,79,81,83,85,88,90,91,94,96,99,100,102,104,106,108,110,112,113,115,117,119,121,123,124,126,127,129,131,132,134,136,138,141)
        AND e.time_elapsed IS NULL
        AND e.time IS NOT NULL
        AND (e.period > 0 OR e.period < 0)
    )
SET time_elapsed = 
    case 
    when evPeriod = 1 AND evTime < 150 then
        evTime*60       
    when evPeriod = 2 AND evTime < 150 then          
        (evTime-45)*60        
    when evPeriod = 3 AND evTime < 150 then    
        (evTime-90)*60           
    when evPeriod = 4 AND evTime < 150 then      
        (evTime-105)*60
    when evPeriod = 1 AND evTime > 150 THEN    
        ROUND(evTime/60)                         
    when (evPeriod = 2) AND (evTime > 150) THEN     
        ROUND((evTime/60)) + 45              
    end;
```

Comment: Tried this method but am receiving the following error : SQL Error: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name
01745. 00000 -  "invalid host/bind variable name"

Comment: Explain plan for this indicated it would take about 71 hours or so to complete. I am hoping there is a solution that could be faster.

Comment: Can you provide the estimation plan? Maybe just try it. Do you have an index on *schedule_id*? Perhaps is looks better with `SELECT e.time_elapsed, e.evPeriod, e.evTime FROM table1.schedule s WHERE s.schedule_id in (22,..) AND s.event_code IN (SELECT e.event_code FROM table2.event e WHERE  AND e.time_elapsed IS NULL AND e.time IS NOT NULL AND (e.period > 0 OR e.period < 0))`